# The vscode server failed to start SSH

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, ssh, remote-access

Trying to connect to a host over the Remote-SSH of Visual Studio Code, I'm getting the following pop-up error:

```
Could not establish connection to 100.xxx.xx.xx The vscode server failed to start SSH
```

On the output terminal following is the error message:

```
[16:22:19.929] > Waiting for server log...
[16:22:19.981] > Waiting for server log...
[16:22:20.034] > Waiting for server log...
[16:22:20.088] >  
> *
> * Reminder: You may only use this software with Visual Studio family products,  
> * as described in the license (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2077057) 
> *
> 
[16:22:20.102] > 
[16:22:20.130] > Server did not start successfully. Full server log at /home/pi/.vscode-server/.
> 7f6ab5485bbc0083e155244e.log >>>
> /home/pi/.vscode-server/bin/7f6ab5485bbc0083e155244e/node: /usr/
> lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (requir
> ed by /home/pi/.vscode-server/bin/7f6ab5485bbc0083e155244e/node)
> /home/pi/.vscode-server/bin/7f6ab5485bbc0083e155244e/node: /usr/
> lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (requ
> ired by /home/pi/.vscode-server/bin/7f6ab5485bbc0083e155244e/nod
> e)
[16:22:20.136] > 
> <<< End of server log
[16:22:20.142] > 
> 2f61c0e4f600: start
> exitCode==32==
> listeningOn====
> osReleaseId==raspbian==
> arch==armv7l==
> tmpDir==/run/user/1000==
> platform==linux==
[16:22:20.148] > 
> unpackResult==success==
> didLocalDownload==0==
> downloadTime==15126==
> installTime==4341==
> extInstallTime====
> serverStartTime==7826==
> 2f61c0e4f600: end
[16:22:20.148] Received install output: 
exitCode==32==
listeningOn====
osReleaseId==raspbian==
arch==armv7l==
tmpDir==/run/user/1000==
platform==linux==
unpackResult==success==
didLocalDownload==0==
downloadTime==15126==
installTime==4341==
extInstallTime====
serverStartTime==7826==

[16:22:20.149] Resolver error: Error: The VS Code Server failed to start
    at Function.ServerInstallError (c:\Users\sa\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.8\out\extension.js:1:39675)
    at u (c:\Users\sa\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.8\out\extension.js:1:391298)
    at Object.t.handleInstallOutput (c:\Users\sa\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.8\out\extension.js:1:39717)
    at Object.t.tryInstall (c:\Users\sa\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.8\out\extension.js:1:48914)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async c:\Users\sa\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.8\out\extension.js:1:45110
    at async Object.t.withShowDetailsEvent (c:\Users\sa\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.8\out\extension.js:1:45660)
    at async Object.t.resolve (c:\Users\sa\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.8\out\extension.js:1:45189)
    at async c:\Users\sa\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.8\out\extension.js:1:52942
[16:22:20.153] ------

[16:22:20.652] > 
[16:22:21.437] "install" terminal command done
[16:22:21.438] Install terminal quit with output:
```

I verified

- both the are in the same network
- the host is reachable by pinging to it
- I'm able to ssh to it on other terminals like command prompt and powershell, I see issue only on the VS Code remote SSH only.
  It was working fine couple of days and suddenly stopped working now.

[VS Code version is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYZSc.png) Version: 1.60.2

Any suggestions on how I can debug and fix this Remote SSH issue?

Comment: It tells you right there: the precompiled binary vscode tries to upload to the remote side requires a newer version of libstdc++ than the one you've got on the remote box. You will need to upgrade the remote box somehow. This can be arbitrarily tricky, depending on the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an issue with the same error message, as I was accessing a Linux server from a Windows machine.
I resolved it by adding a windows firewall rule that allows incoming traffic to VSCode (I had already setup one that allows outgoing traffic before, btw).

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I had the same issue as the OP, and it was because I was running Jesse, which [is nearly 5 years old now](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi_OS).  I updated my Raspberry Pi's kernel from Jesse to Buster (2021) by following this guide: https://djangocas.dev/blog/upgrade-existing-jessie-to-buster-without-re-image/

In short, update the kernel to something more modern.  Short version:

```
$ sudo sed -i 's/jessie/stretch/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
$ sudo sed -i 's/jessie/stretch/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list

$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get -y dist-upgrade

$ sudo reboot
```

Once this is done from jessie to stretch, do the same from stretch to buster (as noted in the linked post).

Once everything is stable, you can install and run vscode-server from a remote box.

Answer (score 0):

@oakad Thank you for the suggesting and pointing to upgrade the libstdc++ on the remote side.

- The host that I was using was RPi 3B Debian(Jessie). I tried to
  upgrade the remote box on vs code and the

> sudo apt-get update

- [This thread](https://github.com/lhelontra/tensorflow-on-arm/issues/13) addressed *libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.22' not found* issue

So tried

> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9
> sudo apt-get upgrade libstdc++6
> ```

was followed by *add-apt-repository: command not found error*
Further tried

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo apt update
```

It did not help and just upgraded RPi 3B to RPi 4
Now Remote-SSH of Visual Studio Code is working perfectly fine on it.
(Not sure if there were some recent updates that no longer supports the older Raspbian version)

Answer (score -1):

I was facing the same issue. This is what worked for me:

1. Select `Remote-SSH: Kill VS Code Server on Host` from the Command Palette of VS Code. This removes the VS Code Server from the remote machine.
2. Establish a fresh connection to the host by selecting `Remote-SSH: Connect to Host...` from the Command Palette and entering your credentials.